# Turning an IP address into a human-readable name

Tags: ip, domain

This is somewhat of a follow-up to my last question, regarding internet radio stations and how to set them up. I've managed to get the software up and running, but the only way that people can connect to it is by entering my IP address + the port number + /stream.ogg. Is there any way (preferably $0) that I can turn this into somehthing like http://myradio.com/stream.ogg? DynDNS might be what I'm looking for but I"m not entirely sure.

Comment: You could buy a static IP, and a domain name to point at that, but dynDNS would do it too - and for free!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DynDNS will do the trick indeed.

here's a tutorial that may be of interest to you:

**[How To: Create a Custom Internet Radio Station](http://www.maximumpc.com/article/how_to_create_a_custom_internet_radio_station)**

Part 2 is dealing with DynDNS setup.